# Different Maybe Types When Inspecting in GHCI

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, option-type

I'm new to Haskell and trying to teach myself the ropes, so forgive me if this is a basic question.

If I open up the interpreter (ghci), why do I get different types as below:

`Just 54`
the type is
`Just 54 :: Num a => Maybe a`

`Just 54 :: Maybe Int`
the type is
`Just 54 :: Maybe Int`

`Just "Stack"`
the type is
`Maybe [Char]`

I don't understand why the first example above yields a type other than `Maybe Int`

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num

Comment: Haskell numeric literals are polymorphic, so they can be used to represent any type that implements the `Num` typeclass. Therefore, the type of any numeric literal is actually of type `Num a => a`.

Comment: try `Prelude> :i Num` and see the list of its instances. In addition to `Int`, there's the `Integer`, `Float` and `Double`, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `54` can be of *any* numeric type. Try e.g. `Just 54 :: Maybe Float`.

If you don't specify any, and the compiler can not pick a precise one, it will keep the most general type for it -- `Num a => Maybe a` means that it can be any type of the form `Maybe a`, as long as `a` is numeric.

Note that, when you try to print it, GHCi plays some tricks and chooses `a` for you. This is called "defaulting". Otherwise, entering `54` and pressing enter, we would get `Ambiguous type error: (which numeric type?)`, which is inconvenient.